# Is the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] php var based off of the users TCP/IP?

Tags: php, tcp, ip, protocols

Is it 100% guaranteed that the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] variable is based off of the users TCP/IP and therefor is always reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope , there is no 100% guarantee. You will get a false positive address when user is behind a proxy internet address.

Comment: Okay, but would that ip address be based off of the TCP protocol?

Comment: Yes it is based on the TCP , If they are using proxy you should be able to capture it by `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` , alternatively you save this `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` too. Well, once again you can't rely on this.